# Nodejs application memory usage tracking and clean up on exit

Tags: node.js, express

"A Node application is an instance of a Node Process Object".[link](http://www.codingdefined.com/2015/04/process-object-in-nodejs.html)

Is there a way in which **local memory on the server** can be cleared every time the node application exits.

[By application exit i mean that when each individual user of the website shuts down the tab on the browser]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

node.js is a single process that serves all your users.  There is no specific memory associated with a given user other than any state that you yourself in your own node.js code might be storing locally in your node.js server on behalf of a given user.  If you have some memory like that, then the typical ways to know when to clear out that state are as follows:

1. Offer a specific logout option in the web page and when the user logs out, you clear their state from memory.  This doesn't catch all ways the user might disappear so this would typically be done in conjunction with other optins.
2. Have a recurring timer (say every 10 minutes) that automatically clears any state from an user who has not made a web request within the last hour (or however long you want the time set to).  This also requires you to keep a timestamp for each user each time they access something on the site which is easy to do in a middleware function.
3. Have all your client pages keep a webSocket connection to the server and when that webSocket connection has been closed and not re-established for a few minutes, then you can assume that the user no longer has any page open to your site and you can clear their state from memory.
4. Don't store user state in memory.  Instead, use a persistent database with good caching.  Then, when the user is no longer using your site, their state info will just age out of the database cache gracefully.

Note: Tracking memory overall usage in node.js is not a trivial task so it's important you know exactly what you are measuring if you're tracking this.  Overall process memory usage is a combination of memory that is actually being used and memory that was previously used, is currently available for reuse, but has not been given back to the OS.  You obviously need to be able to track memory that is actually in use by node.js, not just memory that the process may be allocated.  A heapsnapshot is one of the typical ways to track what is actually being used, not just what is allocated from the OS.